# Android firebase database for every user

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-sqlite

(I searched but I could not see answer about this. Sorry if ı missed.)

I'm new to firebase database. I have an app which has a sqlite db in it. Every user can make updates db because this is actually what app do. for exampe a table lots of knowledge in rows every user changes accordingto himself. 
I wonder is it possible in firebase. 
I want to upload one database first. Every user will changee but everybody will see only hs changes
Thx in advande

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37874920/1531971 (among many others)

Comment: Probably you have no time to read what I ask.

Comment: Why don't you share how all those other references are not relevant? What have _you_ tried? What is your actual question?

Comment: I want have a database which has thousands rows and some columns. I present this db to users, and users will change datas in db. I want every users to see only his changes, my main db to remain same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not a question. It is a story. What do you want to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get?

Comment: I want have a database which has thousands rows and some columns. I present this db to users, and users will change datas in db. I want every users to see only his changes, my main db to remain same.

Comment: @jdv are you ok? why are you so agreesive that show you unneeded

Comment: I am helping you to craft a question that will attract good quality answers. This question is basically unanswerable. Please edit your question to explain as clearly as possible what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you're not capable of understanding clear question, you can do something else

Comment: The question is **not** clear which is why I'm helping you try and clarify it. You can easily [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46591588/edit) the question and say exactly what you want and how it is different from all the ways this is discussed in other places.

Comment: Anyway, if I understand what you want to do (have segmented access to a Firebase instance) the answer is probably "no": https://stackoverflow.com/q/44780725/1531971

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it.. it is just data.. but just bear in mind that Firebase takes in object rather than sql entries.. so, as far as user changes is concerned, and the user can only access the data that he has entered, that is the idea.. you can do it the same as you do with an sql database. 
YOu can see the docs here [https://firebase.google.com/docs/]